# How to enable double tap on an Angular Js application

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, angularjs

I've created an application which enables the user to double click on an item to edit. I'd like to allow the same functionality on mobile devices, meaning the user would double tap to edit the item.

What is the simplest way to implement this? I'd rather not use any additional library (I have heard of Hammer and AngularTouch but haven't used neither before) nor jQuery (in my app I completely forgone jQuery).

If there the only way to implement this is using a library, what would be lightest and easiest?

Many thanks

**EDIT: Adding code**
This is my controller for editing the item:

```
// Double click to edit products
$scope.editItem = function (item) {

    item.editing = true;

};

$scope.doneEditing = function (item) {

    item.editing = false;
    $http.put('/api/users?id' + $scope.User.id, $scope.User);

};

$scope.cancelEditing = function (item) {

    item.editing = false;

};

$scope.deleteItem = function (item) {

    delete $scope.User.todos[item.id];

    $http.put('/api/users?id' + $scope.User.id, $scope.User);

};
```

And this is the my template (Jade)

```
p(ng-dblclick="editItem(todo)", ng-hide="todo.editing").todo-title

    span {{todo.content}}

    form(ng-submit="doneEditing(todo)" ng-show="todo.editing", class="inline-editing-2")

        input(type="text", class="form-control", ng-model="todo.content")

    div.btn-block

        button(class="btn btn-success mr-1", ng-show="todo.editing", ng-click="cancelEditing(todo)")

            span(ng-click="doneEditing(todo)").fa.fa-check-circle

         button(class="btn btn-warning mr-1", ng-show="todo.editing", ng-click="cancelEditing(todo)")

            span(ng-click="cancelEditing(todo)").fa.fa-times-circle
```

So as you can see I use ng-doubleclick to fire my function. I'd need something like ng-double-tab to fire up the double tap. I've been reading more about Hammer and will use [Angular Hammer](https://github.com/dreame4/angular-hammer) for double tap but I'm not sure how it works...

Comment: What have you tried and why didn't it work? If you already created the application; what is the reason for re-writing it?

Comment: please provide your source code my friend

Comment: @JeffryHouser I'm not rewriting, simple adding another function and/or directive to handle the double tapping.

Comment: @code360 I've added the source as requested.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `ios-dblclick`, a directive I wrote to handle double click event on mobile browser (write it for iOS, but works on other browsers). It has no dependency and works like `ng-dblclick`.
It's available [here on Github](https://github.com/mrblackus/ios-dblclick).

Here's an example

```
<div ios-dblclick="removePhoto()"></div>
```

Here is the code of this directive

```
app.directive('iosDblclick',
    function () {

        const DblClickInterval = 300; //milliseconds

        var firstClickTime;
        var waitingSecondClick = false;

        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                element.bind('click', function (e) {

                    if (!waitingSecondClick) {
                        firstClickTime = (new Date()).getTime();
                        waitingSecondClick = true;

                        setTimeout(function () {
                            waitingSecondClick = false;
                        }, DblClickInterval);
                    }
                    else {
                        waitingSecondClick = false;

                        var time = (new Date()).getTime();
                        if (time - firstClickTime < DblClickInterval) {
                            scope.$apply(attrs.iosDblclick);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could always implement your own double tap directive. Start by looking at [touchstart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/touchstart) and [touchend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/touchend) . Bind to these events, and check for multiple taps within some designated period of time.

Answer (score 0):

As far as libraries, we've used this to handle doubletaps for mobile devices in angular

https://github.com/technoweenie/jquery.doubletap

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'd rather not use jQuery.

Comment: well angular is already using a pared down version of jQuery, so it wouldn't be terrible

Comment: Its about keeping the app as light as possible using as less libraries as possible. Also, where did you see that Angular uses a watered down version of jQuery? As far as I know, you can use both in conjuction, yes, but I wasn't aware the libraries share any code.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element    If jQuery is available, angular.element is an alias for the jQuery function. If jQuery is not available, angular.element delegates to Angular's built-in subset of jQuery, called "jQuery lite" or "jqLite."
    
jqLite is a tiny, API-compatible subset of jQuery that allows Angular to manipulate the DOM in a cross-browser compatible way. jqLite implements only the most commonly needed functionality with the goal of having a very small footprint.

Answer (score 0):

The solution above is not working on my IOS - But I found an other Solution, which is working fine on my IPhone:

Just sharing for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/3397/

```
fessmodule.directive('onDoubleClick', function($timeout) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function($scope, $elm, $attrs) {            
        var clicks=0;

         $elm.bind('click', function(evt) {
            console.log('clicked');

             clicks++;
if (clicks == 1) {
$timeout(function(){
    if(clicks == 1) {
        //single_click_callback.call(self, event);
    } else {
        $scope.$apply(function() {
            console.log('clicked');
                        $scope.$eval($attrs.onDoubleClick)
                    });
    }
clicks = 0;
},  300);}
         });

    }
};
});
```